# How to trace import of the views in Django

Tags: django

Is there a way to somehow trace importing of the views ? I want to find which one is broken and doesn't import in some situations (which leads to the fact that all url resolving schema in django stops working).

Comment: Please include the error message with the stack trace.

Comment: It crashes even before it gets to Django. It's a pure python compilation error. It's very difficult to debug.

Comment: What do you get when you run manage.py runserver ?

Answer (score 3):

Pretty amazing that no one has suggested pdb. Place the following in a strategic point in your code:

```
import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
```

When execution reaches that point, the dev server will drop into a shell where you can check values of variables, trace the execution, etc.

It works like a standard shell (use any python commands you like), but there's also special commands that let you control the execution. For example `next` will go to the next line (processing the previous line). `continue` will continue execution until the next break point, etc. ([full list of pdb commands](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#id2))

Comment: Well ok, the issue was actually a little different, maybe I should have posted a separate question for this. However I find your answer the most useful. The problem was that I had a lot of modules named the same way but in different places on a project tree. When I attempted to start a server it just printed "Error importing foo". Now the question is - which foo is it. But I resolved the problem in the way that I described in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you get a stack trace? Is `DEBUG` set to `True`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well it's possible to just write

`python -v manage.py <whatevercommand>`

and search for the error in the produced logs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this means you're getting a 501 server error?

If you're using the Apache web server, you can set it to log python errors in the config for the site using the [`ErrorLog` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#errorlog):

```
ErrorLog /tmp/django_errors.log
```

Then in the terminal (or via ssh):

```
tail -f /tmp/djanogo_errors.log
```

And then try to load the webpage in question. You should then be able to see what the error is and fix it.